# YouTube LiveStream is always showing inactive (errorStreamInactive)

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, live-streaming

I'm Trying to transmit my broadcast with YouTubeApi Livestream but,
status of the stream is always getting `ready`

I've already tried with `liveStream.update()` function, but streamStatus value is still `ready`, it is not updating.

And when I'm trying to run `liveBroadcasts.transition()` it's giving me this error:-

```
code:403,
errors:[  
  {  
     domain:'youtube.liveBroadcast',
     reason:'errorStreamInactive',
     message:'Stream is inactive',
     extendedHelp:'https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/transition'
  }
]
```

Comment: Did you check the [URL](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/transition) of the `extendedHelp`? - Quote: "Before calling this method, you should confirm that the value of the `status.streamStatus` property for the stream bound to your broadcast is **`active`**".

Comment: when i'm checking value of bounded stream's `status.streamStatus`, it's always showing `ready`. I've already checkout documentation, but not getting luck. And also used `liveStream.update()` for update status of bounded stream, but still not working.